# Java menu with both Integer and Char

Tags: java

So I have this code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Menu
{
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Menu().use();
}
public void use() {
    int choice;
        while ((choice = readChoice()) != 0){
            switch (choice){
                case 1: ; break;                    
                case 2: ; break;
                case 3: ; break;
                case 4: ; break; 
            }
        }
}

private int readChoice(){
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Main Menu:");
    System.out.println("1. Setting.");
    System.out.println("2. View hardware detail.");
    System.out.println("3. View Log.");
    System.out.println("4. Access Admin Mode.");
    System.out.println("0. Exit the system.");
    System.out.print("Enter a choice: ");
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
}
```

So by now, I should have a menu which will read in the user input until user type in 0. However, instead of having user typing 0 (an integer) to exit, I want the code to stop when the user input 'x' (a character). Is there a way to do this? I'm new to Java.

Comment: In your method readChoice() the scanner is not even in the scope..

Comment: Maybe `scanner.next().charAt(0);` and `readChoice() != 'x'`.

Comment: Please post compilable code, this one is not valid. You probably forgot a closing curling bracket (`}`).

Comment: updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to accept mixed input, both text ("x") and integers.

The `Scanner` class has some utility methods which can detect the Scanner input before it is consumed, for instance `hasNextLine()` or `hasNextInt()`. Using these methods, you can easily detect whether a valid menu choice is entered:

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    // It's an integer
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
    switch (choice) {
        ...
    }
}
else {
    // A scanner input is always parseable as a string
    String choice = scanner.nextLine();
    if (Objects.equals(choice, "x")) {
        // Stop, exit, return, terminate and abort
    }
    else {
        // What happens if the user entered an invalid string?
        // You decide!
    }
}
```

---

#### Further comments

- Each iteration, you create a new Scanner instance. That's unnecessary overhead. You'd better just create one Scanner and then repeatedly accept input:

  ```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(int);
  while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- You should format your code properly. Wrong indentation can easily confuse further readers, including yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `nextInt()`, you can use `next()`. Therefore your choice needs to be defined as a String. After that even if you enter a number like 1 or 2, this numbers will be handled as Strings. After that you can make a case with "1" and one with "x".

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scanner.nextLine().charAt(0)` rather than `scanner.next().charAt(0)`because next will not take newline character and that can skip your new input